# Google Drive API , Changes api - shared files missing parents field

Tags: google-drive-api

I try to sync changes from GDrive, So I'm using the changes api. It works like a charm when I'm using it with `restrictToMyDrive=true`.

But when I tried to expand it to also track shared files `restrictToMyDrive=false` I encounter some major drawback.  I have inconsist results - the `parents` field is missing sporadically.

Let say that we have `user A` that share that folder to `user B`:

`rootSharedFolder` => `subFolder` => `subSubFolder` => `File`

If `user B` calls the changes API relatively close to the time that `user A` share the `rootSharedFolder` , Then in 3/10 times some of the inner folder will be received without the `parents` field.

Even trying to use the `files.get` API on the received changed item , results in empty `parents` field. But if I wait a minute or two and then call it again , the `parents` field does exist in the result.

Anyone else encounter this problem , and maybe have a workaround for it?

Thanks!

> *this behavior happens only when calling the `changes api` close to the time that the other user share you the items*

Answer (score 4):

Parents field may be missing due two factors:

1. A propagation delay
2. Insufficient permissions to see the parents

In both cases you'll notice the same: the `parents` field for the file is missing, at first there is no way to tell in which case you are:

**A propagation issue:**

This may happen when you request some file details related to a shared file not owned by you right after it was shared to you.

You may not be able to find it's related parents at first glance, this is because changes are still propagating on the file system, this is call a propagation issue, it should not last long and it should be possible to identify and solve this inconvenience by retrieving this field data a couple of minutes after the permission changes.

**Not having access to the parents:**

In this case you may have access to a certain file, but not to it's parent folder, thus, you can not get to know what parent it has, because it's not been shared with you.

This is on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.changes.html):

> - parents — A parent does not appear in the parents list if the requesting user is a not a member of the shared drive and does not have access to the parent. In addition, with the exception of the top level folder, the parents list must contain exactly one item if the file is located within a shared drive.

Side note: you may be interested on using SharedDrives, where files are owned by a organization rather than individual users, simplifying the sharing process and maybe avoiding the problems you are facing here.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives

---

**How to know which case is?**

A way to go is to implement an exponential back-off algorithm to try to retrieve the missing parents field, if after a max number of attempts it does not retrieve we are probably on the second case:

```js
exponentialBackoff(getParent, 7, 300, function(result) {
    console.log('the result is',result);
});

// A function that keeps trying, "getParent" until it returns true or has
// tried "max" number of times. First retry has a delay of "delay".
// "callback" is called upon success.

function exponentialBackoff(toTry, max, delay, callback) {
    console.log('max',max,'next delay',delay);
    var result = toTry();
    
    if (result) {
        callback(result);
    } else {
        if (max > 0) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                exponentialBackoff(toTry, --max, delay * 2, callback);
            }, delay);

        } else {
             console.log('we give up');   
        }
    }
}

function getParent() {
    var percentFail = 0.8;
    
    return Math.random() >= 0.8;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it's the case here. If I wait with the changes request for a minute (after the user shared it with me) , I get the `parents` field correctly.
It's only occur when I call the changes API "too close" to the time it have been shared with me.
I do have access to the parent folder of the files missing the `parents` field.
I test it with the same folder been shared. and got inconsist results.
I ran this test over 100 times , sometimes have it and sometimes don't.
And i'm building a product that is also for personal use - so SharedDrives isn't quite the solution for me.

Comment: Then, in this case it is a propagation issue, there isn't much to be done except to wait and check it again after a couple of minutes.

Comment: Yeah , the big issue is to detect if it's this problem or that the changed file really have no `parents`. 
I hoped google will send the changes only after they update all the permissions on their side.

I will give it a try how to detect that issue and maybe find a solution for it.

Thanks Yuri!